# How to define policy for a list or array in laravel?

Tags: laravel, permissions, authorization, roles, laravel-passport

I have the following policy which determines if a user is able to view a contract.

```
public function view(User $user, Contract $contract)
    {
        if ($user->user_type->id == 2) { // If user is a vecino
            if ($user->id == $contract->customer_id) {
                return true;
            }
        } else if ($user->user_type->is_admin == true) { // If user is an admin
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
```

Which is then checked for authorization with

```
$this->authorize('view', $contract);
```

How do I check authorization for a list/array/collection? Like if I get a list of contracts via `Contract::all()`

I haven't found any way to do this. I could do a loop and call $this->authorize for every iteration to check for authorization but that might impact performance.

Is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: How do you determine if a contract is viewable by an user? does it have a relation?

Comment: If it is a normal user, the contract has to have the user's id in it. As for an admin, it should always be allowed. It is already shown in my code above where it checks if the user id is equal to the contract's customer id.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out and / or did my answer help?

Answer (score 3):

One solution I am currently using is a hybrid approach where you define your rules within a scope and then reference that scope from the policy allowing you to reuse your authorization logic.

```
// Contract model

public function scopeViewable($query)
{
    // If the user is admin, just return the query unfiltered.
    if (Auth::user()->user_type->is_admin) {
        return $query;
    }

    // Check the contract belongs to the logged in user. 
    return $query->where('customer_id', Auth::id());
}
```

And then in your policy, reference that scope but restrict it to the current model. Make sure to return a boolean using `exists()`. This essentially checks that your model is *viewable*.

```
// Contract Policy

public function view(User $user, Contract $contract)
{
    return Contract::viewable()
        ->where('id', $contract->id)
        ->exists()
    ;
}
```

Importantly, you should use the *scope* when retrieving a collection of models and not the policy which would run the scope query for each model in the collection. Policies should be used on individual model instances.

```
Contract::viewable()->paginate(10);

// Or
Contract::viewable()->get();
```

But, when you want to check an individual contract you can use your policy directly.

```
$this->authorize('view', $contract);

// Or
Auth::user()->can('view', [Contract::class, $contract]);
```

Answer (score 2):

The design i often sees in this case, is to check if all elements in the query is allowed to be viewed through the policy. This does not scale well and works bad with pagination.

Instead of filtering out the contracts with policies, the better solution is to filter the contracts already in the query. This mainly because if you want to do pagination down the line, you want to do all filtering before the query is executed to avoid having weird pagination meta data. While also having to run n operations for each element, which would already be a problem at 1000 elements.

There for doing the following query clause, can obtain the same result as your policy.

```
Contract::where('user_id', $user->id)->get();
```

A version of this i usually do to make things easier for my self is creating a scope in the user model.

```
public function scopeOwned($query, User $user)
{
    return $this->query->where('user_id', $user->id);
}

Contract::owned($user)->get();
```

Comment: So the solution is to duplicate your policy logic into scopes? I am not saying you're wrong, but there should be a better way than this.

Comment: But you cant define a policy for an all() / paginate result. Then you have to check the policy against n elements you return. And futhermore, if you make pagination, you will have a hard time applying your policy without breaking the standard pagination approach. Not to mention searching, combined with pagination and policies is not gotta be fun.

For a show() rest api method, of course make a policy. Do you have any better suggestions, i'm curious to here :)

Comment: Agreed that policies should not be used on collections; that is what scopes are for. Policies should be used to verify authorization to a specific model or action. My real concern is _where_ to place the authorization logic so it can be reused in various places. It would suck to have to write it in both the policy and the scope. The cleanest/easiest solution I found is to put your authorization logic into a scope (as you suggested) and then to reference that scope from the policy. I posted my solution. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

You have to loop, one way to another. There is no difference between looping over `Contract` object in your controller, or on your policy, but policies are made to check a single resource so I would do that in your controller.